# How to show just some items in a FlatList

Tags: reactjs, native, flatlist

Let's suppose that I have some datas like this in tempData:

```
tempData = [
    {
        name: "Mark",
        color: "yellow",
       
    },
    {
        name: "Jacob",
        color: "blue",
    },
    {
        name: "Luke",
        color: "yellow",
       
    },
```

And this is my flatlist:

```
        <FlatList
        data={tempData}
        keyExtractor={item => item.name}
        horizontal={false}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        renderItem={({ item }) => 
            <Text>{item.name}</Text>}      
        />
```

This will show:
Mark
Jacob
Luke

But what if I want to show just those that have color equal to "yellow"?

Answer (score 1):

You need to filter data that is passing in `Flatlist` like below

```
data={tempData.filter(temp => temp.color === "yellow")}
```